# Perl is returning hash when I am trying to find the characters after a searched-for character

Tags: regex, perl

I want to search for a given character in a string and return the character after it.

Based on a post here, I tried writing

```
my $string = 'v' . '2';
my $char = $string =~ 'v'.{0,1};
print $char;
```

but this returns 1 and a hash (last time I ran it, the exact output was 1HASH(0x11823a498)). Does anyone know why it returns a hash instead of the character?

Comment: I meant that it's returning a hash even though I want the character. I edited the title to clarify.

Comment: (I removed my comments to clean up as they became unneeded, since you clarified and edited -- thanks :) -- and I added to my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a character after a specific pattern (a character here)

```
my $string = 'example';
my $pattern = qr(e);

my ($ret) = $string =~ /$pattern(.)/;  #--> 'x'
```

This matches the first occurrence of `$pattern` in the `$string`, and captures and returns the next character, `x`. (The example doesn't handle the case when there may not be a character following, like for the other `e`; it would simply fail to match so `$ret` would stay `undef`.)

I use [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator to form a pattern but a normal string would do just as well here.

The regex match operator returns different things in scalar and list [contexts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context): in the scalar context it is true/false for whether it matched, while in the list context it returns matches.  See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut)

So you need that matching to be in the list context, and a common way to provide that is to put the variable that is being assigned to in parenthesis.

---

The first problem with the example in the question is that the `=~` operator [binds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) more tightly than the `.` operator, so the example is effectively

```
my $char = ( ($string =~ 'v') . {0,1} );
```

So there's first the regex match, which succeeds and returns `1` (since it is in the scalar context, imposed by the `.` operator) and then there is a hash-reference `{0,1}` which is concatenated to that `1`.  So `$char` gets assigned the `1` concatenated with a stringification for a hashref, which is a string `HASH(0x...)` (in the parens is a hex stringification of an address).

Next, the needed `.` in the pattern isn't there. Got confused with the concatenation `.` operator?

Then, the capturing parenthesis are absent, while needed for the intended subpattern.

Finally, the matching is the scalar context, as mentioned, what would only yield true/false.

Altogether, that would need to be

```
my ($char) = $string =~ ( q{v} . q{(.)} );
```

But I'd like to add: while Perl has very fluid semantics I'd recommend to not build regex patterns on the fly like that. I'd also recommend to actually use delimiters in the match operator, for clarity (even though you indeed mostly don't have to).

Comment: This works, thank you! I don't quite understand what the period inside $pattern() means, though. Would there be a way to get the next two characters instead of only the next with it?

Comment: @eclare Do you mean the period in `/$pattern{.)/` ?  That `.` is a pattern for any one character; it matches practically anything (except for a newline, and perhaps some other exotic things which I don't know). That is precisely what you need, along with `()` around it, to capture it. So if you wanted two characters, you could say `$p(..)/` or, better, `/$p(.{2})/`.  The `.{2}` means any-one-character, two times (any character followed by any character)

Comment: ( I shortened `$pattern` to `$p` above. the first one should be `/$p(..)/` -- I mistyped it and 'lost' the first, opening `/` )